# Accessing OpenCL GPU from windows 7 through ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, opencl, remote-access, openssh

I have computers where I want to run OpenCL apps remotely using a command line tool, something like the problem described here: http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/160690, but I am with nVIDIA hardware.

I have several computers with W7 and XP where I did install cygwin and OpenSSH. The XP ones, work OK with OpenCL, but not the W7 ones.

Is there any flag, trick, setting that can help be to overcome this problem of Windows? Or in SSHD server?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself:

The easyer way to overcome this problem is to use PSEXEC tool from sysinternals.
However, there are some problems with this tool too.

In order to work properly it is needed:

- An account in the remote computer with proper rights (Admin preferable)
- **Launch PSEXEC in interactive mode (-i)**, otherwise the access to the GPU is not available.
- **Have a local user connected, or a local user was the last one to connect**. If a RDP session is running or the last user connecting has been trough RDP it will likely not work too. Since the GPU will already be disabled.

I am open to accept anyone else's better answer. 
Thank you!